# copyindex() ARM Template Elastic Pool

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template, azure-elasticpool

I try to minimize my ARM Template but I'm stuck here...

My original template is :

```
    "parameters": {
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "resourcegroupName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
.....
        "databases": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "failoverPolicy": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/failoverGroups",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('primaryServer'), '/', parameters('failovergroupName'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "readWriteEndpoint": {
                    "failoverPolicy": "[parameters('failoverPolicy')]"
                },
                "partnerServers": [
                    {
                        "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourceGroups/',parameters('resourcegroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/',parameters('partnerServer'))]"
                    }
                ],
                "databases": "[parameters('databases')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/',parameters('partnerServer'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/',parameters('partnerServer'),'/elasticPools/',parameters('primaryElasticPoolName'))]"
            ]
        },
....
```

and my parameters file contains:

```
    "parameters": {
        "subscriptionId": {
            "value": "11111-4444-5555-666-777777777"
        },
        "resourcegroupName": {
            "type": "RG-ElasticPool"
        },

        "primaryElasticPoolName": {
            "value": "crelasticpool01"
        },

....
            "databases": {
            "value": [
                "/subscriptions/11111-4444-5555-666-777777777/resourceGroups/RG-ElasticPool/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/crelasticsrv01/databases/crelasticdb03",
                "/subscriptions/11111-4444-5555-666-777777777/resourceGroups/RG-ElasticPool/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/crelasticsrv01/databases/crelasticdb02",
                "/subscriptions/11111-4444-5555-666-777777777/resourceGroups/RG-ElasticPool/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/crelasticsrv01/databases/crelasticdb01"
            ]
        },
        "failoverPolicy": {
            "value": "Manual"
        }
    }
```

I would be able to have only :

```
"databases": {
            "value": [
                "crelasticdb03",
                "crelasticdb02",
                "crelasticdb01"
            ]
```

in my parameters file instead of the long id  and concat the long id in my template file

I try with several config like:

```
"databases": "[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourceGroups/',parameters('resourcegroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/',parameters('primaryServer'),'/databases/',parameters('databases')[copyIndex()])]"
```

but I always get an deployment error relative to the copyindex...

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use copy function to create array, unfortunately. you can only create array of objects with it. you seem to require an array of string, which is not possible.

you can work around with nested template and looping, but its a lot easier\cleaner to just go with what you have, tbh.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That's maybe why I tried several options without success.

Comment: its not a comment, its an answer ;) feel free to upvote\accept it :)

Comment: We're working on a fix to generate an array with a copy loop... but not possible today as mentioned.